# How do I remove gridlines in plotly express graph objects (python)

Tags: python, plotly-python

I tried many methods to remove the grid but I am unable to remove these gridlines, any help is appreciated.

[Picture of Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLklZ.png)

```
fig = go.Figure()
for i in dfs:
    k = 2
    for j in selection:
        fig = fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = dfs[i]["Date Time"], y = dfs[i][j], name = "{a} : {b}".format(a=i, b=j), yaxis="y{k}".format(k=k)))
        k+=1
st.plotly_chart(fig, True)
```

Answer (score 5):

try adding these two settings:

```
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False)
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=False)
```

That should get rid of the grid lines

Comment: fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False) and fig.update_layout(xaxis_gridcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')

both work and remove the vertical lines, but no matter what I try the horizontal lines remain

removing yaxis="y{k}".format(k=k) worked, and using your code, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is an overkill,

but try `fig.update_layout(template='simple_white')`

[Plotly templates reference](https://plotly.com/python/templates/)

[Plotly axes: gridlines reference](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#toggling-axis-grid-lines)